# display a table based on value of a column

Tags: angular6

I am learning angular n making a project. [display table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGk7s.png)

I have this above page in which I want to separate the records by type. however I am not able to get the condition right. Can someone help me. Below is my code.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col">
      <h3>Escalations</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="notes.values === 'Escalations' ">
    <app-list-view
        [data]="notes.values"
        [cols]="notes.cols"
        [routeInfo]="notes.routeInfo"
        [sortBy]="'isActive'">
    </app-list-view>
   </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be *ngIf? Which version of angular?

Comment: *ngif was showing me an error, so I tried ng-if

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: angular 6. I just tried again. *ngif works. but above if condition doesn't resolve

Comment: might not be the reason but make sure it is *ngIf (with I in caps)